# How to use ADC1_channel_0 with AutoAnalogAudio?

Tags: c, microcontroller, esp32

anybody know how to use ADC1_channel_5 for recording by AutoAnalogAudio Lib with analogRead(36) -> its AD1_channel_0.

https://github.com/TMRh20/AutoAnalogAudio

I try to disableadc for channel_0 in Lib by method disableAdcChannel() but i got error

```
AutoAnalogAudio-master\src\esp32\AutoAnalogAudio.cpp: In member function 'void AutoAnalog::disableAdcChannel(uint8_t)':
AutoAnalogAudio-master\src\esp32\AutoAnalogAudio.cpp:283:5: error: 'ADC' was not declared in this scope
     ADC->ADC_CHDR |= 1<< pinAx;
```

When I try analogRead - esp32 freeze on this line.

There is any way to read value from channel_0 and record channel_5 by this lib ?